# My program crashes when I try to read a NULL value using sqlite in C

Tags: c, sqlite, coalesce

I have tried to use the below statement to check if the value present in the given fieldname for a record is `NULL` or not, if it is `NULL` then put `0` else return the value present in the fieldname.
It shows syntax error.

```
SELECT [structname.fieldname], isnull([structname.fieldname],0) FROM tablename WHERE condition;
```

Can you please let me know where am I going wrong?

I have also tried the below statement

```
SELECT [structname.fieldname], CASE WHEN [structname.fieldname] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [structname.fieldname] END FROM tablename WHERE condition;
```

For the above statement, the program crashes when it encounters a `NULL` value. Can you please tell me how else can I check if a value of a particular record is `NULL` or not and then read the value if it is not `NULL` else read it as `0`

Comment: What is `structname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using correctly the square brackets.

The column names should be written like:

```
[structname].[fieldname]
```

assuming that `[structname]` is the name or the alias of the table where `fieldname` comes from, and **not** like:

```
[structname.fieldname]
```

which would be ok only if the column's name is actually `structname.fieldname`.

What you need can be done with the function `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE([fieldname], 0) FROM tablename
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Ur suggestion is working for me correctly. My column's name is in the format of structname.fieldname